# How to get all adsets belong to one campaign in Facebook Graph API, Marketing API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I put together this query for `Marketing API`. But it does not return the needed record. Any idea why? It returns 0 record, though adset exists with `campaign_id` `6112214493294`

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/act_10200613422892169/adsets?fields=name,campaign_id&access_token=EAAFuOh2btfQBAKcPPaKxPq4YseAntn6pZBxqFVMUX9tT2lPaQBqfEKMsvlRbadCzyMZAZCesWwtfLmx0mwFGYA3ZBjrHBtX770gS4FNGoZC9gmLK1hIwGOaTkSURKZAjzxzuvFmNcqnXcO4C1lckTuXN9xbWrexfvMesvsxHOzopaInZAy69FNMHDj3Vi92M0jwtDlzK3pwMgZDZD&filtering=[{field: "campaign_id",operator:"EQUAL", value: '6112214493294'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

use `campaign.id` instead of `campaign_id`

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/act_10200613422892169/adsets?fields=name,campaign_id&access_token=EAAFuOh2btfQBAKcPPaKxPq4YseAntn6pZBxqFVMUX9tT2lPaQBqfEKMsvlRbadCzyMZAZCesWwtfLmx0mwFGYA3ZBjrHBtX770gS4FNGoZC9gmLK1hIwGOaTkSURKZAjzxzuvFmNcqnXcO4C1lckTuXN9xbWrexfvMesvsxHOzopaInZAy69FNMHDj3Vi92M0jwtDlzK3pwMgZDZD&filtering=[{field: "campaign.id",operator:"EQUAL", value: '6112214493294'}]
```